# Woocommerce - Add html to the single product page only if there are upsell products

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I wrote this code for display description tab on the left and upsell product on the right in the layout of woocommerce single product. But how avoid this html code if a product have no upsell products at all, and return to the original layout?
This is my custom code:

```
/*** Display description tab and upsell products side by side */

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'ckde_open_container_desc_upsells', 0 );
function ckde_open_container_desc_upsells() {
  echo '<div class=" grid kc-desc-upsells-content"><div class="col-60 kc-desc-container">';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'ckde_close_open_col_desc_upsells', 15 );
function ckde_close_open_col_desc_upsells(){
  echo '</div><div class="col-40 kc-upsells-container">';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'ckde_close_col_upsells', 20 );
function ckde_close_col_upsells(){
  echo '</div></div>';
}

/*** Change number of upsells output  */

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15);
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_upsells', 15);

if (!function_exists('woocommerce_output_upsells')) {
    function woocommerce_output_upsells() {
      woocommerce_upsell_display(6,3); // Display max 6 products, 3 per row
    }
}
```

For sure there is a hook or a conditional tag to do that, but I can't figure out what it can be.
I don't want to override woocommerce template file but do this in my custom functions file
I hope it is clear enough.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way finally!

```
/*** Display description tab and up-sell products side by side when up-sell products are defined */

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'ckde_open_container_desc_upsells', 0 );

function ckde_open_container_desc_upsells() {
  global $product;

  if ( isset( $product ) && is_product() ) {
  
    $upsells = $product->get_upsell_ids();

    if ( count( $upsells ) > 0 ) {

      echo '<div class=" grid kc-desc-upsells-content"><div class="col-60 kc-desc-container">'; 
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'ckde_close_open_col_desc_upsells', 15 );

function ckde_close_open_col_desc_upsells() {

  global $product;

  if ( isset( $product ) && is_product() ) {

    $upsells = $product->get_upsell_ids();

    if ( count( $upsells ) > 0 ) {

      echo '</div><div class="col-40 kc-upsells-container">';   
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'ckde_close_col_upsells', 20 );

function ckde_close_col_upsells() {

  global $product;

  if ( isset( $product ) && is_product() ) {

    $upsells = $product->get_upsell_ids();

    if ( count( $upsells ) > 0 ) {

      echo '</div></div>';  
    }
  }
}
```